# Weird process causing out of memory

Tags: 18.04

On by Ubuntu (Linux jc2hal-new 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) I faced weird issue: once I have series of serious lags, and when I examined dmesg, I see oom-kill killed process named 'rg' several times:

```
$ dmesg | grep "Killed process"
[685948.429421] Out of memory: Killed process 11436 (rg) total-vm:2265220kB, anon-rss:2249532kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[686169.041851] Out of memory: Killed process 12113 (rg) total-vm:1711576kB, anon-rss:1674664kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[686724.302831] Out of memory: Killed process 14217 (rg) total-vm:1658528kB, anon-rss:1643180kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[689403.737894] Out of memory: Killed process 22995 (rg) total-vm:1689408kB, anon-rss:1671980kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[689716.506832] Out of memory: Killed process 23977 (rg) total-vm:1713632kB, anon-rss:1692932kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[689912.849209] Out of memory: Killed process 24900 (rg) total-vm:1641916kB, anon-rss:1626488kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[690116.260516] Out of memory: Killed process 25613 (rg) total-vm:1633988kB, anon-rss:1618496kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

As I check, the 'rg' reffers to 'ripgrep' tool, but it is not installed:

```
$ rg

Command 'rg' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install ripgrep
```

What could it be?
The system has critical requirement for stability, as is is used to aquire data from equipment constantly.